# Cannot Install or update WordPress plugin & WordPress core

Tags: wordpress, plugins, chmod

When i try to update any plugin it will show blank page on the right. No errors displayed.
Uninstall is working perfectly.
Cannot install new plugin & cannot update WordPress Core

NO ERRORS DISPLAYED, only white page on right (you can see side menu of dashboard)

Hosting my Files in VPS - Centos 6 - Apache 2.4.6

Recently i updated PHP 5.3.26 to PHP 5.4.17

I tried Changing Owner Permission to Apache. (i was unable to login - then changes back to my username)

I tried `chmod 777` no use.

I tried adding in wp-config.php - define('FS_METHOD', 'direct'); & chmod 777 to  wp-content directory.

Please help.

Comment: Can you tried viewer log apache: 'tailf /var/log/apache/error.log'?

Comment: [28-Jul-2013 10:04:28 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/homeloader.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/homeloader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER** use `777` permission! Wordpress only need `755` for folders, `644` for files, and `666` for themes and plugins directory recursively. And you might want to give `600` to `wp-config.php`.

I had this problem, I use **CentOS 7** though, this is how I solved the issues.

- Make sure all owned by Apache.
  `sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/sitedir`
- Give proper permissions
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`
  that would give `755` permission to all folder inside `sitedir`
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +`
  that would give `644` to all files
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir/wp-content/themes -type f -exec chmod 666 {} +`
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir/wp-content/plugins -type f -exec chmod 666 {} +`
  those two commands above make 666 permission to all files inside themes and plugins folder
- If you use selinux 

  set this first
  `sudo chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/sitedir`
  then this
  `sudo chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/sitedir/wp-content`
- Restart php-fpm service if you had one.
  **UPDATE:**
  If you don't get through until this point. You might also need to set a local policy module for selinux.
  `sudo grep php-fpm /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol`
  `sudo semodule -i mypol.pp`
  Then restart php-fpm.

As I [cover here](http://www.unixius.com/fail-wordpress-update-plugins-permission-centos/) more detail on my blog :)